# How to unparent a deleted armature?

Tags: armature, parent

I deleted a armature without unparenting it, and now it is affecting my particle system for some reason. The hair particles do not look like they do in particle edit mode, they go in all kinds of directions. Before I parented the armature, they did not do that. What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there are 3 things you can do manually, both in properties panel :

- Remove the armature modifier (click the 'X')
  [image: arma modifier]
- remove the parent manually in object properties (click the 'X')
  [image: object parent]
- remove the armature related vertex group in object data tab (select a group and click the '-' button)
  [image]

Comment: Additionally, if it was an armature deformed object, go and delete all the armature related vertex groups.

Comment: @RadishoftheOpera yup, good point