# alt-p doesn't seem to be doing anything in 2.8

Tags: shortcut

I'm trying to unparent an object from an armature, but alt-p does nothing. I looked online to see if there is a new shortcut for this function, but cannot find anything.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Alt+P should work. There may be something wrong in your settings.

Comment: Other programs also can block a key combination. For example if I install the AMD Radeon ReLieve, I can't use alt+r till I reconfig it in the ReLive settings.

Comment: hmm can't think of what it could be. In Blender 2.7 I was getting this strange proxy warning whenever I pressed alt-p, so I installed 2.8. I don't get the proxy warning anymore, but alt-p does nothing. I can still work though as I can just unparent the object in the armature modifier

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35084/how-to-unparent-a-deleted-armature

Answer (score 0):

Try the other Alt key. In my case only the **left Alt key** (next to the windows key) works.